# How to avoid out of memory in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My app use camera and face detect to check face consecutive and send the image face to the server to check and receive a response to display result so it has a lot of work to do.

My app has to run 24/24 but after about 30 minutes, it started lagging camera preview and crashed. I have checked the memory view and it increase time after time so I think the app crash because of out of memory.

I have tried to use Isolate but feel like it does not work. Anyone can help me?